# Invoke a delegate method from the view controller class

Tags: xcode, methods, delegates, uiviewcontroller

I have declared and Implemented a delegate method in the projectAppDelegate.h and .m files.
Then I created a method in the projectViewController.m class that has to invoke the method which is declared in the delegate file.
The problem is that the view controller does not aware of the delegate function because it is declared in another file.

My question is what is the recommended way to solve that.
Is there a need to import new files?

Thanks in advance,
Sagiftw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `#import "projectAppDelegate.h"` in your view controller class in order for the view controller to be aware of methods declared in your app delegate's interface.

As an additional note, file names of Objective-C classes (and the classes themselves) are usually capitalized (e.g. ProjectAppDelegate.h).